# Yii Framework 2.0 get data from the left table which does not exist as foreign key in the right tabke

Tags: php, relational-database, yii2, join

Working with Yii framework 2.0, I have two database tables (A and B). It is a relational database 1:n. A has only one B but B has many of A. My database looks similar to this.

```
A table:
  id = 1, name = yes
  id = 2, name = no
  id = 3, name = ok
  id = 4, name = good

B table:
  id = 1, a_id = 1
  id = 2, a_id = 1
  id = 3, a_id = 2
```

I would like to retrieve the records from the 'A' table which its primary key does not present in the 'B' table. The result that I want to get is.

```
A table:
  id = 3, name = ok
  id = 4, name = good
```

I don't want to use the following code, because it is not efficient to me.

```
$allA = A::find()->all();   

foreach($allA as $model) {

     if(!$model->getBs()) {
         $allAWithoutB[] = $model;
     }

}
```

How can I define such a relational method or scope BQuery class, so that I do not need to query all A records and filter them in the for-each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that arogachev posted is *almost* correct.

If you were to run his method `getOtherModels()` you would get a 'Cannot convert object to string' exception.

My method below does the exact same, except I have made the method `static` and added a `foreach` to loop through the objects and add the `a_id` values into a new array.

I also added `$condition` argument to the method, so you can add conditions to the A models.

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public static function withoutBModel($condition = null)
{
    $subquery = BModel::find()->select('a_id')->distinct()->all();
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($subquery as $q) {
        $arr[] = $q->a_id;
    }
    $query = static::find()->where(['not in', 'id', $arr]);
    if (!empty($condition)) {
        $query->andWhere($condition);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

The use of this method is as follows:

```
$aModelsWithoutB = A::withoutBModel('active = 1')->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that logic it's not suitable for relation.

You can use the query with subquery. First of all select all unique `a_id` from `b` table, then exclude it in selection from `a` table. Put this method in your `AModel`.

```
public function getOtherModels()
{
    $subquery = BModel::find()->select('a_id')->distinct()->all();

    return static::find()->where(['not in', 'id', $subquery]);
}
```

You can put this in [scope](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#scopes) if you want.

Comment: Could you please provide me more information how I should call this getOtherModels() method? Because now I tried it this way: $modelObject->getOtherModels()->all(); but it does not work.